# SSMS 19 connecting error with local or azure db

Tags: sql-server

I just encountered an error with my SSMS. Typically I have am connected to 3 Azure servers and one local(the desktop).Keep in mind that I didn't use visual studio to establish the connection, I just opened the Studio to check something. When I started the studio and none of them were there. When I clicked on Browse for more: I selected the desktop since I didn't see anything else. When I clicked connect I got this message:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893019)

Opening SQL studio and connecting to my dbs

Comment: Keep in mind: Search Engine exist, and are an incredibly useful tool.